# PHP, получение названия объекта в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

У нас имеется массив следующего содержания

```
array(1)
{ 
["таблица 1"]=> array(3) 
    { 
        [1]=> 
            array(4) 
            { 
                [0]=> string(31) "Название таблицы" 
                [1]=> string(0) "" 
                [2]=> string(0) "" 
                [3]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
        [2]=> 
            array(4) 
            { 
                [0]=> string(16) "колонка 1" 
                [1]=> string(16) "колонка 2" 
                [2]=> string(16) "колонка 3" 
                [3]=> string(16) "колонка 4" 
            } 
        [3]=> 
            array(4) 
            { 
                [0]=> string(5) "д1.1" 
                [1]=> string(5) "д2.1" 
                [2]=> string(5) "д3.1" 
                [3]=> string(5) "д4.1" 
            } 
    }
}
```

Как получить название объекта, "таблица 1"? и если их несколько то как получить все?

Извиняюсь за столь простой вопрос, просто в гугле не могу сформировать запрос так что бы ответ найти, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно подойдет функция `array_keys`

https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php

```
$keys = array_keys($arr); //$arr - ваш массив
```

`$keys` будет массивом, значениями которого являются ключи из массива `$arr`.

В догонку пример из официальной документации

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

Выведет:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => color
)
```

Comment: Впишите ключевые моменты в тело ответа, ссылка на stackoverflow не являеться ответом.

Comment: Буду крайне признателен за пример, и как дальше работать с ключами , как я понял что то вроде этого:

     $key = array_keys($array); 
     echo $array[$key[0]][1][0]; 

Так мы должны получить имя таблицы из моего примера массива, да?

Comment: Да я правильно понял, все работает, но почему-то: echo $array[$key[0]][1][0]; дает результат "Название таблицыNULL", кто подскажет почему?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров, а кроме указанного кода больше ничего не выполняется? NULL мог быть выведен уже другим оператором echo в коде позже.

Comment: @DanielOlivo, да вы совершенно правы! недосмотрел, спасибо!